# Debian Testing SDDM Does not Log In Users

Tags: debian, sddm

I have a strange problem. I'm running a Debian testing installation and recently with KDE5 update stream, I got SDDM instead of KDM. However, SDDM does not log me in even when I enter my correct password. When I enter my password:

- SDDM disappears and looks like login is starting.
- After some time, SDDM re-appears.

However, if I shutdown SDDM, start X from my user, export display and run `startkde`, I can use KDE as usual.

The logs doesn't show anything worthy.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update 1:** Running SDDM from console creates no logs on the console. Other logs (syslog, messages, et al.) show that SDDM tries to start the session, but the session just quits. Strange.

**Update 2:** I found the relevant log entry: `Auth: sddm-helper exited with 2.` Which means `pam_backend->openSession()` somehow gives an error and exits. However, everything is fine with PAM, groups, file permissions and other details. I cannot trace it to the real reason yet, because SDDM logging doesn't help much.

**Update 2.1:** Looks like it's related with `PAM`, but PAM stack doesn't give any visible errors.

Comment: You could check the exact commandline SDDM uses when is runs with `ps aux`. Then you stop it, and attempt to run is in the foreground on say tty1. Then login as user, and use the root-console to observe any SDDM output.

Comment: Looking it now...

Comment: Sorry, but SDDM doesn't give any output to console during its operation.

Comment: This happened to me as well, have you solved it? How did you find out what is happening with PAM?

Comment: Did you try any other display managers?

Comment: The problem has solved itself with an SDDM update. I've used XDM for the meantime. Problem was not from PAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved itself after an update. Probably it was a bug with SDDM and there was no problem with the PAM since I've used XDM for the meantime.